# Converting data queried from Hive Tables to JSON or any other single line format

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have HTML content in one of the columns , I would like to query that column
and convert that to a single line string to be able to pass it to a script.
In the below query I would like to convert 'Body.Content' as a single line . As this content contains a lot of new line characters and tabs , whereas SampleHive.exe will get the input as only single line separated with tabs for each argument.

```
SELECT TRANSFORM (Body.Content, DateTimeReceived, Importance) USING 'SampleHive.exe' AS (Content string, DateTimeReceived string, Importance string) FROM message_table LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I tried regexp_replace(Body.Content,'\r\n|\t','') this totally replaces new line characters and tabs . But it may effect the further processing in script so I want someway we can get the complete original string.

Comment: you need regexp to parse html.

Comment: could you please explain little more how to use it..thanks

Comment: Sorry i thought wrong. It is not possible with html parser.
why don't you write UDF for your case ?

Comment: yeah I think that's the only way..thanks